# Errror when trying to updateChildren at FirebaseDatabase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, runtime-error

I am trying to program a Chat Application. But when I try to send a message, by updating Children in my RealtimeDatabase from Firebase I am getting this error:

```
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
```

And this error goes on and on for a few pages.
But I dont know why it happens. Is there a limit of how much I can write to the Database at once?

Comment: By the way I am getting only this error when I try to update FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats").child("userchats").child(myUiD).child(UiD).updateChildren(map); this. When I comment this out it is working fine.

Comment: Please add also your build.gradle file.

Comment: add your code...

Comment: i found my error: I dont know why but I wasnt able to put FirebaseAuth to the hashmap

Comment: FirebaseAuth isn't an allowed value. While updateChildren takes a  map of <String, Object> there is no checking on the types you put into Object. You can only put String, Long, Double, Boolean, Map<String, Object> and List<Object> into Firebase values (see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Comment: @KarlWolf can you share your solution as an answer to this question?