# write object with url to firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, url, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to write an object, which includes a URL as one of its attributes, to my firebase database. It is failing with the error below.

**Error**

*This error is longer (really long) but it just repeats the following and then ends here*

> at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeas.zzbu(Unknown Source)
>   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzear.zzbq(Unknown Source)
>   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzear.zzbt(Unknown Source)
>   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeas.zzbu(Unknown Source)
>   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzear.zzbq(Unknown Source)
>   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzear.zzbt(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeas.zzbu(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzear.zzbq(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzear.zzbq(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzear.zzbp(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                               at
>   com.companyName.appName.MyActivity.postDataToFirebase(MyActivity.java:582)
>                                                                               at
>   com.companyName.appName.MyActivity$13.onSuccess(MyActivity.java:551)
>                                                                               at
>   com.companyName.appName.MyActivity$13.onSuccess(MyActivity.java:543)
>   at com.google.firebase.storage.zzj.zzi(Unknown Source)
>   at com.google.firebase.storage.zzaa.run(Unknown Source)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

I was able to track down that it crashes when I include my URL in the object I am writing to firebase, but it does not crash when I omit the URL.

**Post Function in My Activity**

```
public void postDataToFirebase() {
    Log.d(TAG, "triggering postDataToFirebase...");
    Uri myURL = https://somewebaddress.com/subpath%2Fotherpath%2FanotherPath%2FV3ipNtaGW3tG%2FhairColor%2F-Op032Dasdfie41ZB98d%2FeyeColor%2F3%2FasdfEesWEWf1341DfWds342%2FintroductionVideo.mp4?alt=media&token=a457i222l-6c6a2-2524l4-zy3m-p7384eo295d0di1;
    String greetingValue = "Hi there!";
    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());
    Log.e(TAG, "This is the current time = " + timestamp);
    // Create HashMap of all details to post
    Map<String, Object> childUpdate = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdate.put("firstName", firstNameTextField.getText().toString());
    childUpdate.put("lastName", lastNameTextField.getText().toString());
    childUpdate.put("hairColor", hairColorTextField.getText().toString());
    childUpdate.put("greetingValue", greetingValue);
    childUpdate.put("timestamp", timestamp);
    childUpdate.put("URL", myURL);  // **NOTE: If I comment out this line, no error occurs 
    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: childUpdate");
    Log.d(TAG, childUpdate.toString());
    // **ISSUE: The error occurs on the line below
    myRef.child("somepath")child(userId).child("someotherpath").setValue(childUpdate);
}
```

**Build.Gradle (app)**

*I am including this because it was asked for in the question referenced below*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1"
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

List<String> dirs = [
        'main',     // main sample code; look here for the interesting stuff.
        'common',   // components that are reused by multiple samples
        'template'] // boilerplate code that is generated by the sample template process

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.appname"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 19
        versionName "4.8"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            dirs.each { dir ->
                java.srcDirs "src/${dir}/java"
                res.srcDirs "src/${dir}/res"
            }
        }
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
        androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']

    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true // Enables code shrinking for the release build type.
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Additional:**

I also found this question which appeared to be similar based on the error, but I checked and I am able to make updates (which was not possible in this question), making me think this is not the same issue.

- [Errror when trying to updateChildren at FirebaseDatabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194089/errror-when-trying-to-updatechildren-at-firebasedatabase)

**Does anyone understand why my post to firebase is succeeding when I don't include the url but failing when I do (and how to prevent it)?**

Comment: Can you double-check that the code you have posted accurately reflects what you are running?  The last statement contains `setValue(childUpdates)` (note the 's' at the end of `childUpdates`), but the map you build in the preceding code is named `childUpdate`.

Comment: @BobSnyder the post should now accurately reflect what I am running. I am running `childUpdate` everywhere (no `childUpdates`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Uri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) is not one of the [native types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#setValue(java.lang.Object)) supported by Firebase Database for storing.  You need to store the string equivalent instead:  `Uri.toString()`.

Later when you read the string and want to recreate the `Uri`, you can use [Uri.parse()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 1):

myURL type is URI & firebase does not allow to store URI. Firebase allows only String, Long, Double, Boolean, Map, List.
(see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).

If you want to store your URL, store it in String.

```
String myURL = "https://somewebaddress.com/subpath%2Fotherpath%2FanotherPath%2FV3ipNtaGW3tG%2FhairColor%2F-Op032Dasdfie41ZB98d%2FeyeColor%2F3%2FasdfEesWEWf1341DfWds342%2FintroductionVideo.mp4?alt=media&token=a457i222l-6c6a2-2524l4-zy3m-p7384eo295d0di1;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into a string and then upload into firebase database

Comment: Can you help me with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438092/in-app-billing-connect-to-firebase-and-get-products) please?